# Oracle SQL Sequence number in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What can I do if I wish to use a sequence number in a WHERE clause?

Here I wanna use the last value gebarated by the sequence in the WHERE clause

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_no_s
    INCREMENT BY 5
    START WITH 100;

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (
    my_no_s.NEXTVAL,
    TO_DATE('2023/10/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    3
);

INSERT INTO myTable (m_no, m_datetime, m_roomno)
SELECT  my_no_s.NEXTVAL,
        my_datetime + 10,
        my_roomno
FROM myTable
WHERE my_no = my_no_s.CURRVAL - 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anonymous PL/SQL block

```
DECLARE
seq_curr_value NUMBER;
BEGIN

  -- Select current value of sequence
  SELECT my_no_s.CURRVAL INTO seq_curr_value FROM dual;
  
  INSERT INTO myTable (m_no, m_datetime, m_roomno)
  SELECT  my_no_s.NEXTVAL,
          m_datetime + 10,
          m_roomno
  FROM myTable
  WHERE m_no = seq_curr_value - 5;
END;
/
```

PS: You have to edit your column names in select list also.
Example: not **my_datetime** but **m_datetime** and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You tried, and you failed - that's expected because of certain **restrictions** on sequence usage. Have a look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm#SQLRF50944) which says

> **Restrictions on Sequence Values**
>
> You cannot use CURRVAL and NEXTVAL in the following constructs:
>
> (...)
>
> The WHERE clause of a SELECT statement

You've already got one answer (anonymous PL/SQL block). Another might be your own function which returns that value.

Sample table and sequence:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE mytable
  2  (
  3     m_no         NUMBER,
  4     m_datetime   DATE,
  5     m_roomno     NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE my_no_s INCREMENT BY 5 START WITH 100;

Sequence created.
```

Initial row:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO myTable
  2       VALUES (my_no_s.NEXTVAL, TO_DATE ('2023/10/03', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 3);

1 row created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_curval
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS
  4     retval  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT my_no_s.CURRVAL INTO retval FROM DUAL;
  7
  8     RETURN retval;
  9  EXCEPTION
 10     WHEN OTHERS
 11     THEN
 12        RETURN NULL;
 13  END;
 14  /

Function created.
```

This is your 2nd attempt (which failed), but now - in line #4 - it calls a function. I also modified constant you used (`0` instead of `5`) as there aren't any more rows in that table so `where` would cause 0 rows to be inserted at this moment):

```
SQL> INSERT INTO myTable (m_no, m_datetime, m_roomno)
  2     SELECT my_no_s.NEXTVAL, m_datetime + 10, m_roomno
  3       FROM myTable
  4      WHERE m_no = f_curval - 0;

1 row created.

SQL>
```